# fprintf not printing to a file,when file pointer declared elsewhere

Tags: c++, file, printing

I have the following files- `SymbolTable.cpp`, `SymbolTable.h`, `demo.y`,`demo.l` and `log.txt`

The driver function(main) is in the `demo.y` file.

I declared `FILE *logout` in `demo.y`.But when i do `fprintf(logout,"prinit sth");`in any function of `SymbolTable.cpp` it is not printing anything. I have added the header file in the remaining three files, and also included `extern FILE *logout` in the other files.

Is there anything else that I have to include so that `fprintf` works properly.

P.S it prints fine when i call `fprintf` from `demo.l`

`SymbolTable.cpp`

```
#include "SymbolTable.h"
#include "SymbolInfo.h"
#include "ScopeTable.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<map>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int tableSize = 7;
extern FILE *logout;

SymbolTable::SymbolTable()
{
    cout<<"in SymbolTable constructor"<<endl;
    fprintf(logout,"in SymbolTable constructor\n");

}
```

`demo.l`

```
%option noyywrap
%{
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#include "SymbolTable.h"
#include "SymbolInfo.h"
#include "ScopeTable.h"
#include "y.tab.h"

void yyerror (char *);
extern YYSTYPE tag ;    
extern SymbolTable *table;
extern int tableSize;

extern FILE *logout;
extern FILE *temp;

%}

id [a-z]*
newline \n
ADDOP "+"
digit[0-9]

%%
......remaining code
```

demo.y

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>  
#include<string.h>
#include "SymbolTable.h"
#include "SymbolInfo.h"
#include "ScopeTable.h"
//#define yydebug 1

int yyparse(void);
int yylex(void);
extern char * yytext;
extern FILE * yyin;
extern int tableSize;
//extern FILE *temp;

SymbolTable *table;

FILE *logout;
void yyerror (const char *s)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",s);
    return;
}

%}
%%

%%
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    table = new SymbolTable();
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp = fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("cannot open file");
        exit(1);
    }
    logout = fopen("log.txt","w");
    //temp = fopen("temp.txt","w");
    yyin = fp;
    yyparse();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: If you're programming in C++, why don't you use C++ file streams?

Comment: cuz i find it even more difficult

Comment: Opening a C++ file stream is just as easy, and formatted output is just the same as for `std::cout` (which includes type-safety that the `printf` family lacks). There's also a couple of other things, like you using a pointer for the `SymbolTable` object, which is really not needed.

Comment: As for your problem, with the code as you show it, it's impossible to help you as it should work fine. Perhaps check that the `fopen` call succeeded?

Comment: As for how you can possibly help yourself, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). And if possible, try to [find a simpler problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/) As for the last part (simpler problem) a common way to accomplish that is by simplifying your code, possibly by starting over and adding one small piece at a time, testing that everything works before adding the next small piece. And of course enable verbose warnings by the compiler, to see if it notices something.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to print to the log file (in the `SymbolTable` constructor) before opening it.

Comment: i opened it in `main()`,shouldnt that work

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a look at part of your `main` function:

```
table = new SymbolTable();
// Other irrelevant code...
logout = fopen("log.txt","w");
```

When you do `new SymbolTable()` you create the object and *construct* it. That means your `SymbolTable` constructor will be called. And it happens *before* you open the file.

This means that you will call `fprintf` passing a *null pointer* for the file, as otherwise uninitialized global variables will be "zero" initialized (which for pointers means they will be null pointers). Using a null pointer leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and I would say that you're *unlucky* the program didn't crash.

You need to change the order, or not print anything in the constructor.

Comment: i did `logout = fopen("log.txt","w");` then `table = new SymbolTable();`still not working. are you talking about this order?

Comment: @afsara_ben Yes that order, and if that doesn't work then there is something else wrong that you don't show us. How do you check the results? Perhaps all you need is to `fflush` the file after printing?

Comment: im attaching the files wait. i considered that it would be too much code so i included a portion of it